# Настройка двух параллельных связей в EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ninject, codefirst

Привет всем!
Cтолкнулся со  следующей проблемой: есть пользователь **ApplicationUser:IdentityUser** и группа **Group**. Пользователь содержит две коллекции - созданные им группы **CreateGroups** и присоеденённые группы **JoinGroups**, группа содержит ссылку на своего создателя **Creator** и её участников **Members**. Т.е имеются две параллельные связи many-many и many-one. К моему сожалению, не удается корректно настроить связи.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // созданные группы пользователя
    public virtual ICollection<Group> CreateGroups { get; set; }
    // присоединенные группы
    public virtual ICollection<Group> JoinGroups { get; set;}
}

public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; protected set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DTCreate { get; set; }

    // создатель группы
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Cоздание с Fluent Api

```
public class ApplicationDbContext :IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(c => c.CreateGroups)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Creator)
            .Map(p => p.MapKey("CreateGroupId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.JoinGroups)
            .WithMany(g => g.Members)
            .Map(ug =>
            {
                ug.MapLeftKey("UserRefId");
                ug.MapRightKey("GroupRefId");
                ug.ToTable("UsersJoinGroups"); /*создаётся таблица

            });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

При попытке создания группы возникает ошибка `System.InvalidOperationException: 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'`

GroupsController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateGroup(CreateGroupBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        string currentUserId = GetUserIdentityId();
        var currentUser = AppUserManager.GetCurrentUser(currentUserId);

        var group = new Group()
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Description = model.Description,
        };

        group.Creator = currentUser;    
        group.Members.Add(currentUser);

        _service.Create(group);
        _service.Commit();
        return Ok(group);          
    }
```

Уже пробовал настраивать связи аннотациями

```
    // созданные группы пользователя    
    [InverseProperty("Creator")]
    public virtual ICollection<Group> CreateGroups { get; set; }
    // присоединенные группы    
    [InverseProperty("Members")]
    public virtual ICollection<Group> JoinGroups { get; set; }
```

и

```
    // создатель группы
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }        
    // участники группы
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Members { get; set; }
```

PS. EntityFramework6, Asp.Net WebApi 2, Identity, Ninject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё разобрался! Дело было не в связях.
Дело было в контекстах, создаваемых OWIN и Ninject. Решил добавлением в BaseApiController

```
private GroupService _groupService = null;
    protected GroupService GroupService
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupService ??
                Request.GetOwinContext().Get<GroupService>();
        }
    }
```

и регистрацией GroupService в Startup приложения

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<GroupService>(GroupService.Create);
```

И теперь GroupService использует тот же контекст, что и UserManager.
Группы создаются.